# Translate a text into a set of inference rules

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm working on a question from one of my past college test.
I have to translate a text into a set of formal rules of inference.
The text is:

*"Ugo is a LP student that also writes software in Snowball. Anyone who writes software in Snowball finds a good paid job. So we can say that some LP student can find a good paid job."*

Since there are quantifiers I assume it's a first-order logic problem, so I defined the individual constants and the predicates:

$C=\{ugo\}$

$P=\{LPS, SD, GPW\}$

Where:

1. LPS mean LP student
2. SD mean Snowball developer
3. GPW mean good paid worker

My try with the rules:

[maybe modus pones]
$$
\frac{(\forall x)(SD(x)\rightarrow GPW(x)), SD(ugo)}{GPW(ugo)} 
$$
[dont know if its a real rule]
$$
\frac{LPS(ugo), GPW(ugo) }{(\exists x)(LPS(x), GPW(x))}
$$

Answer (score 1):

"I have to translate a text into a set of formal rules of inference". Eh? Really?? You can't translate *propositions* into *rules of inference* - they are different kinds of thing entirely. Propositions are true or false; rules of inference truth-preserving or otherwise.

The informal inference

> Ugo is a LP student that also writes software in Snowball. Anyone who writes software in Snowball finds a good paid job. So we can say that some LP student can find a good paid job

can be regimented

> $$(Lu \land Su),\ \  \forall x(Sx \rightarrow Gx)\ \therefore\ \exists x(Lx \land Gx)$$

using obvious letters for the predicates and '$u$' as a constant denoting Ugo to translate the three propositions involved. The obvious proof showing that the conclusion does indeed follow from the two premisses would go

> $$ \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(Lu \land Su) \quad\quad\quad  \forall x(Sx \rightarrow Gx)\\
>  \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\_\_\_\_\_\_\quad\quad\quad\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\\
>   (Lu \land Su)\quad\quad\quad Su \quad\quad\quad\quad (Su \to Gu)\\
>  \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\quad\quad\quad\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\\ Lu \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad Gu\quad\quad\quad\\
> \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\\
> (Lu \land Gu)\\
> \_\_\_\_\_\_\\
> \exists x(Lx \land Gx)$$

where the rules used are And-Elimination (twice), Universal Elimination [a.k.a. U. Instantiation], and Modus Ponens, and then And-Introduction, and Existential Introduction. [Or a rearrangement of that proof, if you use e.g. a Fitch-style system.]

Comment: Well probably my traduction was wrong, it say:
*Formalize using rules of inference and say which one are used.*

Comment: This answer it's great, thank you alot.

Comment: Given this answer, how would you define the **horn** clause?